# UITabBar without upper separator for the selected images

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I need to create an `UITabBarController` which selects the button in such way:

[image]
<sub>(source: [cs14108.vk.me](http://cs14108.vk.me/c402818/v402818064/ad94/rHSL9l1LHHI.jpg))</sub>

The selected tab shouldn't have the top separator. Is it possible to perform without subclassing UITabBarController?

Comment: Kudos for the toilet paper

Comment: @Mikael, it's a napkin

Comment: Yeah I can see that, but it made me happy :)

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't changing the background image/color (something that would apear just like your views background) of your tabs for the selected state help you?